# Minikube portainer externalName not working

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress, portainer

I deployed portainer using this:

```
kubectl apply -n portainer -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/portainer/k8s/master/deploy/manifests/portainer/portainer.yaml
```

I created namespace "portainer" before.

I want to access portainer via ingress.

I created service with externalName

```
    kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: portainer
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: portainer.portainer.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 9000
```

Here is my ingress config

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /portainer
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portainer
            port:
              number: 9000
```

And here I don't know why but I have this problem when i call "kubectl describe ing"

```
/portainer   portainer:9000 (<error: endpoints "portainer" not found>)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a clusterIP type service instead of an external name

Answer (score 0):

The `(<error: endpoints "portainer" not found>)` is caused by the fact that you didn't assign namespace to `ingress` object which is namespaced:

```
kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true | grep ingress
ingresses                   ing          extensions                  true         Ingress
ingresses                   ing          networking.k8s.io           true         Ingress
```

So in order to change it you have to assign it to `portainer` namespace:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: portainer
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /portainer
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portainer
            port:
              number: 9000
```

There is a service created during deployment (`kubectl apply -n portainer -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/portainer/k8s/master/deploy/manifests/portainer/portainer.yaml` ) so there is no need to create new one, you can simply refer to it in `ingress` object.

Then it will be assigned to your service created in this namespace:

```
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /portainer   portainer:9000   172.17.0.3:9000)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  47m   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress portainer/ingress-nginx
  Normal  UPDATE  47m   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress portainer/ingress-nginx
```